# Oracle loader skip lines

Tags: oracle

In a CSV, using oracle loader, how can I skip lines that aren't the header?
For exemple:

```
Names;Initials
SomethingForSkip
Name1;Inital1
Name2;Inital2
SomethingForSkip
Name3;Inital3
Name4;Inital4
```

At the moment I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE t_ext_course(
UC  CHAR(100),
SCIENTIFIC_FIELD    CHAR(10),
DEPARTAMENT CHAR(100)

)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
    TYPE oracle_loader
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY src_files
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY newline
        BADFILE 'course.bad'
        DISCARDFILE 'course.dis'
        LOGFILE 'course.log'
        SKIP 3
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        (
            UC              CHAR(100),
            SCIENTIFIC_FIELD    CHAR(10),
            DEPARTAMENT     CHAR(100)
        )
    )
    LOCATION ('course.csv')
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: After your `SKIP` entry, add a `LOAD WHEN` entry.

Comment: Thank you @MatthewMcPeak. So, after Skip, Should I use LOAD WHEN (SCIENTIFIC_FIELD != BLANKS)? Thats what I found on oracle docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch12.htm)

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak already tested and it work perfectly fine, please can you answer the question so I can mark it was an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LOAD WHEN` parameter.  You would put it in right after your `SKIP 3` parameter.

With `LOAD WHEN`, you can specify conditions so that only the source file rows meeting that condition will be loaded.

**SQL*Loader** and, by extension, external tables of type `oracle_loader` offer a `BLANKS` keyword that you can use to check for empty fields.  It is useful for delimited data where you do not know the field length.

You can put it all together like this:

```
LOAD WHEN (SCIENTIFIC_FIELD != BLANKS)
```